# custom field (video/audio url) and embed functionality

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, embed

I was wondering if there is any way to combine a custom field (in custom post type) with an embed shortcode? Long story short - a user type into a field called videox and an url for a video (youtube, vimeo) or audio (e.g. soundcloud). When I render this field, of course it displays as it was in the field. How do I convert such input into  an embeded audio / video?

I've tried to echo that input between embed (as `do_shortcode('[embed]' . $adresgoeshere . '[/embed]');`) yet without success.

Comment: Just checking I'm understanding you. You have a CPT with two fields. User type and url and you are trying to display them with a shortcode? Also could you post all code relating to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using URLs from oEmbed provides (YouTube, Vimeo, Soundcloud, etc), I would use [`wp_oembed_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_oembed_get/) function. This function uses oEmbed and tries to get the embed HTML of the provided URL.

```
$embed = wp_oembed_get( $some_url );
if( $embed ) {
   echo $embed;
} else {
   // The embed HTML couldn't be fetched
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another way here. You can leave this to WordPress and just pass the URL from [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter.

Example:-

```
$adresgoeshere = 'URL of oembed providers'
echo apply_filters('the_content', $adresgoeshere);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of do_shortcode you can use the run_shortcode function of $wp_embed

```
global $wp_embed;
$embed = $wp_embed->run_shortcode( '[embed]' . $url . '[/embed]' );

echo $embed;
```